# How to multiupload images in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to do multi upload photos to the form in Codeigniter 3. When I want to upload photos, clicking upload sends me the entire form and adds only one photo. If anyone could give me tips on how to do this, I would be grateful. I could do it as two separate forms but then it doesn't work as I would like.

My form view

```
<form method='post' action='<?php echo base_url();?>ads/create' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-4 col-form-label text-uppercase text-right">Tytuł :</label>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title"  value="<?php echo set_value('title'); ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="message" class="col-4 col-form-label text-uppercase text-right">Opis ogłoszenia:</label>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <textarea name="description" id="message" cols="70" rows="5"
                                              class="form-control" ><?php echo set_value('description'); ?></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="contact" class="col-4 col-form-label text-uppercase text-right">Osoba do kontaktu:</label>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact"  value="<?php echo set_value('contact'); ?>">
                                </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-4 col-form-label text-uppercase text-right">Adres email:</label>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" <?php      if ( logged_in() == true )
                                                                        { echo "value='".$user->email."' disabled";      } ?> >
                                </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="phone" class="col-4 col-form-label text-uppercase text-right">Numer telefonu:</label>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone"  value="<?php echo set_value('phone'); ?>">
                                </div>

                                                                    </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="message" class="col-4 col-form-label text-uppercase text-right">Zdjęcia:</label>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                             <input type='file' name='files[]' multiple=""> <br/><br/>

                             <input id="submit" type='submit' value='Upload' name='upload' />
                            <strong><?php if(isset($totalFiles)) echo "Successfully uploaded ".count($totalFiles)." files"; ?></strong>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary w-50 mt-3">Dodaj</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

And my controller

```
public function create()
    {

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata( 'id' );
        $where = array( 'id' => $user_id);
        $user = $this->Site_model->get_single('users', $where);
        $data['user'] = $user;


        if ( !empty( $_POST ) )
        {

            if ( $this->form_validation->run( 'site_ads_create' ) == true )
            {

                if ( logged_in() == true ) 
                {
                $data = array(
                    'email' => $this->session->userdata( 'email' ),
                    'title' => $this->input->post( 'title' , true ),
                    'description' => $this->input->post( 'description' , true ),
                    'category_id' => $this->input->post( 'category_id' , true ),
                    'city_id' => $this->input->post( 'city_id' , true ),
                    'price' => $this->input->post( 'price' , true ),
                    'contact' => $this->input->post( 'contact' , true ),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post( 'phone' , true ),
                    'user_ip' => getUserIpAddr(),
                    'created' => time(),
                    'active' => 1,
                );
                }
                else
                {
                $data = array(
                    'title' => $this->input->post( 'title' , true ),
                    'description' => $this->input->post( 'description' , true ),
                    'category_id' => $this->input->post( 'category_id' , true ),
                    'city_id' => $this->input->post( 'city_id' , true ),
                    'price' => $this->input->post( 'price' , true ),
                    'contact' => $this->input->post( 'contact' , true ),
                    'email' => $this->input->post( 'email' , true ),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post( 'phone' , true ),
                    'user_ip' => getUserIpAddr(),
                    'created' => time(),
                    'active' => 0,

                );  
                }



            $count = count($_FILES['files']['name']);



      for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){



        if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][$i])){



          $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];

          $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];

          $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

          $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];

          $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];



          $config['upload_path'] = 'images/'; 

          $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';

          $config['max_size'] = '5000';

          $config['file_name'] = $this->input->post( 'title' , true );



          $this->load->library('upload',$config); 



          if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){

            $uploadData = $this->upload->data();

            $filename = $uploadData['file_name'];



            $data['totalFiles'][] = $filename;

          }


        }


      }
                $this->Site_model->create( 'ads' , $data );
                $ad_id = $this->Site_model->last_id();


                if ($this->input->post('promo' , true ) == 'tak' ) 
                {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('promo_id', $ad->id);

                    redirect( 'ads/promo' );
                }

                $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , 'Ad has been added.' );
                 //refresh();

            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , validation_errors() );
                //refresh();
            }



        }


        $data['cities'] = $this->Site_model->get_cities('cities', 'name', 'asc');
        $data['categories'] = $this->Site_model->get_categories();
        $this->load->view( 'create' , $data );


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should change

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
```

> into

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('files')){
```

> Future reference Check the link to learn how to upload multiple files in codeigniter
>   [Multiple upload in codeigniter](https://github.com/eboominathan/Multiple-upload-in-Codeigniter-using-Dropzone.js)

Answer (score 0):

in this example you you have single image upload and multiple image upload different folders.

if ($param =="upload") {

```
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/user_profil/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 15000;
    $config['file_name']             = $this->input->post('user_profile')."_profil_image_".mt_rand(100000,900000);

        $this->load->library('upload', $config, 'user_profile'); // Create custom object for cover upload
        $this->user_profile->initialize($config);


        if ( !empty($this->user_profile->do_upload('user_profil_image') ) )
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->user_profile->display_errors());

            $file_name_profile_picture = $this->input->post('user_profil_image_actual');

            $upload_data = $this->user_profile->data(); 
            $file_name_profile_picture = $upload_data['file_name'];
        }
        else
        {           
            $file_name_profile_picture ="";

        } 

        //map photos
        $config_galery['upload_path']          = './uploads/map_profile/';
        $config_galery['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config_galery['max_size']             = 15000;
        $config_galery['file_name']             = $this->input->post('name')."_user_profilm_map_".mt_rand(100000,900000);


        $this->load->library('upload', $config_galery, 'map_profile'); // Create custom object for cover upload
        $this->map_profile->initialize($config_galery);


        if ( !empty($this->map_profile->do_upload('map_profile_image'))  )
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->map_profile->display_errors()); 

            $map_profile_image =$this->input->post('map_profile_image_actual');

            $upload_data1 = $this->map_profile->data(); 
            $map_profile_image = $upload_data1['file_name'];


        } else {

            $map_profile_image="";
        }


        if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])){ 
            $b = $this->doupload_gallery(); 
            $galery_photo_links =  json_encode(json_decode($b, true));

        } else  {
                // default empty state
            $galery_photo_links ="[]";
        }  


        if (!empty($this->input->post('profile_qr_id'))) {

            $data_update_qr_status = array(
                'statusi' => 1,
                'table_name' => "table_name_db"
            ); 

            $this->db->where('profile_qr_id', $this->input->post('profile_qr_id'));
            $this->db->update('table_name', $data_update_qr_status);  


        } 
        $this->db->insert('table_name', $data); 

// ridirect      
 redirect(base_url('admin/uploads_view'), 'refresh');
```

}